# Azure Bot is not Responding On Teams

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, botframework, microsoft-teams

I have a bot built with Microsoft Bot framework Node.JS SDK, the bot is deployed on a windows server and has been working well for over a year.

Just a few days ago, the Bot stopped responding, checked the bot's log and came across this error.

```
node:14628) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.
(node:14628) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: BotFrameworkAdapter.processActivity(): 400 ERROR
 SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\BotServiceToken\node_modules\botbuilder\lib\botFrameworkAdapter.js:1262:37)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:482:12)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1221:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
    at BotFrameworkAdapter.<anonymous> (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\BotServiceToken\node_modules\botbuilder\lib\botFrameworkAdapter.js:687:27)
    at Generator.throw (<anonymous>)
    at rejected (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\BotServiceToken\node_modules\botbuilder\lib\botFrameworkAdapter.js:12:65)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:14628) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
(node:14628) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Note: The bot works well when I test with the Botframework Emulator.

Is there a way to solve this, I have checked the  botFrameworkAdapter.js file mentioned in the error but I can't seem to find the bug.

Comment: Could you please share the minimal sample code?

Comment: Also, which version of the SDK are you using? There have been a number of updates to the SDK since a year ago.

Comment: Hi @Nivedipa-MSFT, please sample the code of which file. Is Okay if i paste the line of the Botbuilder file flagging the error?

Comment: @StevenKanberg, I'm using SDK v4.7.0

Comment: Hello @Folorunso - Looks like the issue due to the depreciation of packages. Please try updating your node package and check it once?

Comment: Hi @ChetanSharma-msft , thanks I will do that and let you know if there is any improvement

Answer (score 0):

Just like the warning said

DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.

To avoid the depreciation warning. You need to find out the new Buffer() methods in your codes and replace them with a new one.